# Why does this code NOT get all my Jenkins views?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

Jenkins v2.263.3 (old I know)

I've Googled here and other Jenkins groups and see this code to get all the views

```
import jenkins.model.*

def jenkins = jenkins.getInstance() // or simply jenkins.instance
def views = jenkins.getViews() // or simply jenkins.views
for (view in views) {
  println view.getDisplayName()
}
```

the above code only prints the "All" view. What's missing? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided should work for new and old Jenkins versions including version **v2.263.3**.
You can also use the following shortened syntax (tested in the Script Console):

```groovy
Jenkins.instance.views.each {
   println(it.displayName)
}
```

However, this will not show views that are defined inside Folders, it will only show views that are defined in the main hierarchy level of Jenkins. To show all the views including Folders and nested Folders you will need to iterate over all folders (Folder items) and extract the views from them.
Something like:

```groovy
println("Main Jenkins Views")
Jenkins.instance.views.each {
    println(it.displayName)
}

println("Folder Views")
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder.class).each { item ->
    println("\nViews for Folder ${item.name} (${item.fullName})") 
    item.views.each { view ->
        println(view.displayName)
    }
}
```

You can also extract more information regrading the views such as `primaryView` and similar from both the main object and the Folder one, you can see [Here](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/cloudbees-folder/com/cloudbees/hudson/plugins/folder/Folder.html) some of the available options.